# What is the best way to get a decimal or a float result when dividing two numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I declared a variable @avgMis as a decimal(2,2) in SQL Server. Then I tried to divide two integers, expecting a decimal value. Instead my answer is 0.00.

How do I divide @avgMis = (1/(1+2+1)) to get 0.25 in SQL Server?

Comment: `select 1.0/(1+2+1);` or `select 1/(1.0+2+1);`

Comment: The numerators and denominators in your division were integers.

when we divide integer 1 by integer 4 result is 0, which in your case was stored in @avgMis so became 0.00

To avoid integer division add multiplication with say 1.00 [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba8cdac9998684fbd13cfd0e37f8d1b5)

Comment: Is it not possible for your result to be 1 or is the numerator always less than the denominator?

Comment: More often than not, you're not the first person to come across an issue, and can often solve the problem faster by viewing existing answers than waiting for new ones. See [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=divide+two+integers+sql-server&searchOn=3), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast as decimal

```
DECLARE @x INT = 10, @y INT = 3, @z decimal(6,2)
SELECT @z = CAST(@x AS decimal(8,4))/CAST(@y AS DECIMAL(8,4))
SELECT @z
```

result would be 3.33

in your situation

```
SELECT CAST( CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(6,2))/CAST((1+2+1) AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS result
```

[image]

Comment: I also found that by using actual decimals in my input values, the return result is also a decimal, i.e., select 1.0/(1+2+1); or select 1/(1.0+2+1);